# How to change the anode on this water heater?

Tags: water, water-heater, hot-water

I have a Bradford White water heater installed in 2011. I was following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3bY1UR77Dw) to replace the anode. I was expecting my water heater to look like in the video, with a clear nut to unscrew.

[image: youtube image]

However, my water heater looks different, it seems to have one piece at the bottom. (I sanded what looked like a seem ...)

[image: my water heater]

Wider shot:

[image: wide angle]

How do I replace the anode?

Additional images: https://imgur.com/a/4VTTcfC

Answer (score 3):

That is a solder union.

Turn off the tank.  Will need to close the cold water valve to the tank or the house(main).

open a hot water valve above in the house and drain the tank to below the top of the tank(drain water from the pipes).

Will need to heat the solder with a torch or cut the pipe and add an union/coupling.

Remove the nut and replace the rod.

Fill the tank, close hot water faucet once no more air comes out, check for leaks, turn on tank.